# input text with "ngModel" show his value only after defocus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularjs to fill a group of inputs inside a form.

For filling those inputs, i'm using a json data and it works, however, the inputs doesn't show/display the values until i select the input and then click anywere else in the page (defocus).

this is my code(javascript/angularjs):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
    app.controller('registerController', function($scope,$timeout,connectWS) {
        $scope.start = function(){
            connectWS.getPerson(2,function(response){
                var data = JSON.parse(response.response.result.result); //<----JSON data
                $scope.register=data; //<-----value assignation
            });
        };
    });

app.factory('connectWS', function($http){
        return {
            getPerson: function(idVal,callback){
                var formData = '{'+
                    '"data": {'+
                        '"id":"'+idVal+'"'+
                    '}'+
                '}'; 

                var request = {
                    'function': 'getdata',
                    'parameters' : formData
                };

                var op = gapi.client.request({
                    'root': 'https://script.googleapis.com',
                    'path': 'v1/scripts/' + SCRIPT_ID + ':run',
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'body': request
                });

                op.execute(callback);
            }
        };

...


...

function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'scope': SCOPES,
            'immediate': true
        }, function(authResult){
            var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("registerEditionDiv")).scope();
            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.start();
            });
        });
    }
```

the code run after this:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth"></script>
```

this is my code(html/angularjs):

```
<div class="regiRow"><p>Nombre:</p> <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="register.name"/></div>
                            <div class="regiRow"><p>Fecha de nacimiento:</p> <input type="text" id="birthdate" ng-model="register.birthdate"/></div>
```

Comment: can you please share the definition of your connectWS.getPerson function? I would like to test this in jsfidle. And were do you call the $scope.start function?

Comment: Hola: Please build an jsfiddle, I cannot see anything wrong in your code.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that he´s defining  $scope.start as an function but does not call it anywere inside the code. It should be $scope.start = connectWS.getPerson(.....);

Comment: @MartinGodzina, pdorgambide. question updated with more code

Comment: Try to define your $scope.start not as a function: $scope.start = connectWs.....

Comment: @MartinGodzina i'm using start as a function because i need to call it after the google api resource is loaded, if i call "connectWs" directly in the controller, the "google api" objects will not be created and the page will throw a bunch of errors

Comment: really strange. I cant figure out what is causing this problem.

Comment: I would try defining $scope.register.name and $scope.register.birthdate at the top of your controller. I'm guessing its an issue with the controller creating default variables when encountering the ng-models, and the $watch not inspecting inside an object.

Comment: @MattW i've tried that, and it assign the values on startup but in the moment when i call "$scope.start" the values are not refreshed. i've solved the problem adding "$scope.$digest();" but i don't know what it does.

Answer (score 0):

for a reason that i don't know right now, the problem is solved adding "$scope.$digest();" in "$scope.start" function. something like this:

```
$scope.start = function(){
            connectWS.getPerson(2,function(response){
                var data = JSON.parse(response.response.result.result); //<----JSON data
                $scope.register=data; //<-----value assignation
                $scope.$digest(); //<------Magic
            });
        };
```

i really don't know why, i guest maybe is because that function is called with "$scope.$apply(function())" but i'm not sure. i still noob with everything about angular.

Comment: $scope.$digest() is the internal function Angular uses to update the view from the model and vice-versa. $scope.$apply() performs a function and then calls $digest() automatically. I think your issue is that your callback is performed asynchronously, and so is outside of the $apply() loop. Try moving your $apply from the start() to where you save the data to $scope.register.

Comment: @MattW i did your recommendation and it work. the part where i assign the values are  surrounded by $scope.$apply and i've removed $scope.$digest from the script.

i guess that's a better solution because i've removed unnecesary code.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I would research how Angular watches objects--there are several methods it can use. I think that this is probably an edge case where Angular is choosing the wrong method based on your ng-model method. You might also experiment with a $scope.$watch or $watchCollection instead of a $digest as it might be faster.